# Proving ODE is periodic if and only if p(t) is periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Consider the first-order nonautonomous equation $x′ = p(t)x$ where
$p(t)$ is differentiable and periodic with period $T$. Prove that all solutions
of this equation are periodic with period $T$ if and only if  $\int_0^T p(s) ds = 0$.

Chapter 1, exercise 14 from http://www.amazon.fr/Differential-Equations-Dynamical-Systems-Introduction/dp/0123820103

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x(t)=e^{\int^t_{t_0}p(s)\,ds}x(t_0)$ and to be $T$-periodic you should have $x(t+T)=x(T)$ for all $t$.

Note that one should perhaps distinguish between periodic and constant, and even consider the smallest period.

Comment: I need one more hint